# Azure DevOps build pipeline stuck at loading build history

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

Azure DevOps build pipelines stuck at loading the build history, It is happening for few pipelines but rest are fine. When I recreate these pipelines with same templates, those all are working fine and showing the build history, but am worrying why particular these pipelines are not showing. We are using the other git connection for these pipelines. Is it because of too long build history.
I use the filters to load the history. Its working fine with **feature** and **other** branches and showing the history but not for **Main** branch. Am confusing why it is not loading the build history for the **Main** branch. How can I sort out this issue. Please someone help me on this. Am sharing the pics of above issue with and without filters. Thank you.

Without filters continuous loading page
[image]

child branch build history with filters
[image]

Main branch continuous loading page with filters
[image]

Picture for retention policies
[image]

Pipeline retention policy
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is caused by long build history on the main branch. Since it shows correctly when recreating these pipelines with same templates.

In Azure DevOps, you could use [Retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to set how long to keep runs, releases, and tests stored in the system. To save storage space, you could delete older runs, tests, and releases.

[image]

[Pipelines - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) API is supported to get all the history runs from a specific pipeline.

[image]

**Update 1**

I have checked the official doc for Azure DevOps Server.

This API is supported via TFS2020.

[image]

But not supported via TFS2019.

[image]

For TFS and API version mapping, you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#api-and-tfs-version-mapping).

For [Version 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) supported API. I could see there is API to get the builds by build ID, but not pipeline.

[image]

**Update 2**

You could check why this run is being retained on the pipeline summary page.

[image]

[image]

For GitHub repo, as addressed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#set-run-retention-policies),

> All other Git repositories: Azure Pipelines retains the configured
> number of latest runs for the whole pipeline.

There are other related settings could affect the build pipeline retention policy, for example, if the build pipeline provides an Artifact.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the above api works for Azure DevOps Services cloud, Could you please share me the api for get the list and delete particular builds from the list for Azure DevOps server. I couldn't find them anywhere. These mostly available for cloud version but am looking for server 2019. Please help me

Comment: Hi @Harish334363 , I have added Update above in the previous answer, you could have a check.

Comment: I use the GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0 to load the builds. It is loading all builds in the project. But I don't know how to get the particular pipeline build history with API for Azure DevOps Server 2019. Please help me on this. So that I can delete the builds to sort out the issue

Comment: yeah that is the problem to load the builds from particular pipeline. I can't check for all builds, there is a large build list in the loaded data. Confusing why this is not available for 2019 Devops server or Is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: Currently the Pipelines-List does not apply to TFS 2019. Have you tried using InPrivate Window of your browser or changing another browser for an attempt?

Comment: ya, I upgraded it to the TFS 2020 server and it is supporting with api 6.0. I got all the builds of the particular pipeline. Thank you so much. Now I wanted keep build history of 2 months and delete the rest build history at once instead of deleting single runs. because it is taking longer time and continuous thing. I wants to clear the history for many pipelines. please help me, is there any possible way to delete all build runs at once in particular pipeline.

Comment: You could follow my previous to use Retention Policy, the policy will take one day to reflect. API is supported to delete by {buildID}: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0. But you need to run multiple times, API could only delete one run per time.

Comment: I just now added the retention policies page. According to that, It should be delete the old history more than 30 days. But why am having the build history from Jan'2022. What are the changes I should made on policies for only 2 months build history. Please guide me

Comment: As per above retention policy settings it should delete all the build history except the 30 days. But why it is not deleting the build history. Is it works with other git repositories. because these pipelines are connected with github repos by Other git service connection.

Comment: Hi, I have a second Update in the post, you could check the corresponding setting.